# Generating every single combination from a few hashes

Tags: ruby, permutation, combinations

I have a few arrays, I'll just say four. For instance:

```
LOCATION  = [:new_york, :california, :alaska, :missouri, :mississippi, :florida]
TYPE      = [:high_rise, :mid_rise, :low_rise, :loft, :townhouse, :hotel]
OWNERSHIP = [:coop, :condo, :condop, :rental, :single_family, :multi_family]
BLDG_AGE  = [:historic, :pre-war, :post-war, :modern]
```

I need a script that generates every combination of these. Here are some examples:

```
:new_york
:new_york, :high_rise
:new_york, :high_rise, :coop
:new_york, :high_rise, :coop, :historic
```

These are the easy ones, just a bunch of nested loops. I also need other combinations. For instance:

```
:new_york, :coop
:new_york, :pre-war
:new_york, :rental, :modern
:new_york, :high_rise, :single_family
```

But just think every combination with the exception that only members of `LOCATION` can appear alone.

Comment: Have you considered [this](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-combination) or [this](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-permutation)?

Comment: Just 4 basic loops will do the trick.

Comment: I'm working on an answer that doesn't require you to say how many arrays are going to be present.. but it's taking a bit.

Comment: Your code is not valid Ruby. Particularly, `:pre-war`, `:post-war` are not.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you wanted `:pre_war`, `:post_war` instead of `:pre-war`, `:post-war`:

```
LOCATION  = [:new_york, :california, :alaska, :missouri, :mississippi, :florida]
TYPE      = [:high_rise, :mid_rise, :low_rise, :loft, :townhouse, :hotel]
OWNERSHIP = [:coop, :condo, :condop, :rental, :single_family, :multi_family]
BLDG_AGE  = [:historic, :pre_war, :post_war, :modern]

LOCATION.product([nil] + TYPE, [nil] + OWNERSHIP, [nil] + BLDG_AGE)
.map(&:compact)
```

Or more condensed:

```
LOCATION.product(*[TYPE, OWNERSHIP, BLDG_AGE].map{|a| [nil] + a})
.map(&:compact)
```

Comment: awesome answer.  I spent an hour re-learning a bunch of ruby array method functionality to put together a similar, but much less ruby-ish answer, and your solution is much more friendly.